# Halt registration when certain conditions are (not) met

Tags: users

On registration we have to look up the user-information in a remote database (JSON service), when user is not found there, or when some other error occurs, we want to halt the registration completely.

```
function foo_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $foo_bar = new FooBarSource($edit["foo_bar_invite_code"]);
  if ($foo_bar->is_valid()) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Fail'), 'error');
    //What now?
  }
}
```

Problem is that I fear some records are being written already in, or before [hook_user_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_user_presave/7). From the documentation:

> A user account is about to be created or updated.

Is it safe to simply do a `drupal_goto()` to halt the registration? Would that cause orphaned records in the Database? What about other modules implementing this hook: would they break or be confused?

Is this hook the proper hook to determine if a user can register?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) for user registration form, and add extra validation function to the form using [#validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#validate) like below.

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'extra_user_validation';
```

in function extra_user_validation set error after validation. So, that you can avoid the submit process and invoking hooks.

```
function extra_user_validation($form, &$form_state) {
   // Get the input values of registration form from $form_state['values']
   // Do validation & set error
}
```

That should work !

Comment: You must user [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) to set the error and cancel the changes.